# How to compile page with play/pause button

Tags: typescript, vercel

I have this function in my code:

```
  const handlePlay = () => {
    const audio = audioRef.current
    if (audio!.paused) {
      audio.play()
      setIsPlaying(true)
    } else {
      audio.pause()
      setIsPlaying(false)
    }
  }
```

When I try to compile that on Vercel, it fails with `Type error: 'audio' is possibly 'null'.`.

When I force `audio` to not be null like this:

```
  const handlePlay = () => {
    const audio = audioRef.current
    if (audio!.paused) {
      audio!.play()
      setIsPlaying(true)
    } else {
      audio!.pause()
      setIsPlaying(false)
    }
  }
```

It does not like that either, saying: `Property 'play' does not exist on type 'never'.`

How can I compile this?

Answer (score 0):

You should add a check on `audio`.

```
if (!audio) return;
```

Then you'll not have to force `audio` not to be `null`.

You can also check the play and pause functions like so:

```
if (audio?.play) audio.play()
...
if (audio?.pause) audio.pause()
```

Comment: when I try that, it throws an error on the `play` and `pause` vars: `Property 'paused' does not exist on type 'never'.ts(2339)
`

Comment: here is the full code: https://gist.github.com/reallymemorable/54b93af83f9508e2c885ce63abe2ca40